# Pointers in C , understanding the difference

Tags: c, pointers

```
void noOfClients(struct noOfClients *q );
```

I understand that a pointer's name holds the memory address of a variable.

But, when `*` comes with a pointer, it represents the content of that location.

In the above line of code, when passing a by reference, we'd say:

```
void noOfClients( &q);
```

But why?

Thank you.

Comment: `Struct*` is a type: a pointer to an Struct. `*ptr` is an expression (a value). The fact that they both use `*` is confusing.

Comment: Is void noOfClients( &q); a call to function or a prototype of function

Answer (score 2):

`*` has different meaning when it is used in a variable/argument declaration and when it is used as a pointer dereference operator.

In a variable/argument declaration, it declares the variable/argument to be of a pointer type.

```
struct noOfClients *q
```

declares `q` to be a pointer to a `struct noOfClients`.

When used in an expression,

```
*q
```

dereferences where `q` points to.

**PS**

```
void noOfClients( &q);
```

is not the right way to call the function. Just use:

```
noOfClients(&q);
```

That will work if `q` is declared as an object.

```
struct noOfClients q;
noOfClients(&q);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void func(foo *a);
```

This is a function prototype of a function taking a pointer to a `foo`. Some people like to write this as

```
void func(foo* a);
```

There's no difference, but you might say that the function takes a "`foo`-pointer", rather than a "pointer to a `foo`".

- `a` is a `foo*`
- `*a` is a `foo`

There is no difference.

Answer (score 0):

because & indicates the address of a particular variable and when you deal with functions so when you pass a variable to the function so you do some changes in that variable, sometimes the reflection of value are not done in that variable but  if you pass a variable with its address then reflection will be done properly just try and understand following two codes it will sure help you

without &

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    void swap(int, int);

    int main()
    {
       int x, y;

       printf("Enter the value of x and y\n");
       scanf("%d%d",&x,&y);

       printf("Before Swapping\nx = %d\ny = %d\n", x, y);

       swap(&x, &y); 

       printf("After Swapping\nx = %d\ny = %d\n", x, y);

       return 0;
    }

    void swap(int a, int b)
    {
       int temp;

       temp = b;
       b   = a;
       a   = temp;   
    }
```

> with &

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(int*, int*);

int main()
{
   int x, y;

   printf("Enter the value of x and y\n");
   scanf("%d%d",&x,&y);

   printf("Before Swapping\nx = %d\ny = %d\n", x, y);

   swap(&x, &y); 

   printf("After Swapping\nx = %d\ny = %d\n", x, y);

   return 0;
}

void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
   int temp;

   temp = *b;
   *b   = *a;
   *a   = temp;   
}
```